# Django how to display img in template by setting MEDIA_ROOT

Tags: django

here is my settings

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'upload/'
MEDIA_URL = '/upload/'
```

where the path of upload folder is `PROJECT_ROOT/myapp/upload`.

I successfully upload a file a.jpg to that folder, but in the render page it shows that `/upload/a.jpg` not found

I'm confused about the media root setting. I think it's similar to STATIC_URL,
my static url setting is like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/
```

and the path of static folder is `PROJECT_ROOT/myapp/static`

and files like `/static/a.css` can ben rendered successful in web pages.

Comment: Static is for all the images, CSS, JS etc that is in your app. The `collectstatic` management command collects all of that and puts it in your `STATIC_ROOT`. You use the `{% static "" %}` template tag for these in html files. Anything uploaded via file fields & similar is put in the `MEDIA_ROOT` and for those, you use the URL attr of the file field or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media_root is the absolute path of the folder where your media files are being stored. 'upload/' is not an absolute path.

If you're storing your media files locally (development server) it would be something like (on windows)

`c:\my_app_path\media`

You can hard code it or you can use the os.path.join command :

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

more informations [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Francois